# Uploading a geodataframe with some missing geometries using 'to_postgis'

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, geoalchemy, sqlalchemy

I have a GeoDataFrame with plenty of info, including a 'geometry' column. Some of the rows have no geometry data... I simply don't have it. I decided to leave those rows as 'None' or 'NoneType' in the geometry column. This would be a representation of my GeoDataFrame:

```
   person  job         geometry
1  bob     Musician    POINT(1234.1234123 1234123.234)
2  john    Accountant  None
3  Sandra  Banker      POINT(234234.2343 23423.234)
...
```

I have tried with this:

```
engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:5432/{}'.format(user, password, host, database))

customers.to_postgis(
    con=engine,
    name="customers_db"
)
```

But of course, Python complaints:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_geom'

How can I still upload the GeoDataFrame? I do not want to get rid of those customers without coordinates as they still have valuable info + I could obtain it later in time.

Comment: This might be useful.  You may need to assign empty geometry in you dataframe for the missing geometry.  https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/missing_empty.html

Comment: I don't have an environment where I can test it right now, so this answer may not be perfect, but give it a try. Change None of GeodataFrame geometry to Polygon(None) using shapely.  
from shapely.geometry import Polygon ;
gdf.loc[gdf['geometry'].isna(), 'geometry'] = Polygon(None);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So thanks to the comments I was able to find an answer. The simplest way to create a 'geometry nonetype' is by creating an empty geometry. This is a representation of what I did:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf['geometry'][0] = Point()
```

That creates an empty geometry value.